# Help Correlating Particle Count (Dirtiness) to Chip Pass/Fail

Tags: regression, machine-learning, binary-data, continuous-data, discrete-data

I have two datasets that I’d like to correlate in a way that is helpful and predictive.

In our process, we a have a single work piece that should be perfectly clean that will eventually become many microchips after processing. Because nothing is perfect, this work piece is dirty and depending on how dirty it is, it could lead to a failure down the line in processing.

I have two data sets:

--- Categorical Data -- Pass/Fail of each chip on the work piece on the backend of the process.

--- Continuous Variables -- Particle (dirtiness) information – particle counts, size, and location in X/Y. – This is taken before processing with a fancy tool.

--- ((Also, general location data about where on the work piece the chips are. ))

I’d like to learn the following in the end.

- How dirty is too dirty?
- When should we save process time by skipping induvial chips on the work piece, or maybe by scrapping the workpiece all together.
- Is there a particle size that almost guarantees a failure?

I’m thinking to start, I can break my particle data down into an array such that each index is a chip #, and then fill the arrays with data like Max Particle Size, Particle Count, Total Particle Size and then compare that data and to my Pass/Fail variable.

However, is there a better way? I kinda have a 2D map with discrete points of dirtiness, as well as a 2D map with pass/fail data. Can these be correlated in a better way? I think this approach is better than a 1D approach since it’ll help deal with the case of a neighboring particle causing defects to all it’s surrounding chips.

All ideas appreciated .

Comment: as a very general guideline:

1) set aside a validation set of data
2) apply various [classification models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html)
3) visualize the results
4) choose some "finalist" models
5) test them on your validation set, and pick the best model

Comment: All of these things are big subjects in and of themselves.  You'll probably get better help by getting started, and then asking more specialized questions as they come up.